# Using array of strings for axis but last one is missing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have another question for you guys. I build a weather-app and I´m trying to show the times of the forecast in the x-axis which is working ok, but what´s strange is that the last value of the array is missing.

Code for the axis looks like this:

```
var axisscale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(arraytime)
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width]);

console.log(arraytime);


var xscale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, width]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(axisscale)
    .tickValues(arraytime)
    .tickSize(6, 0)
    .orient("top");
```

And you can see my array called "arraytime" in the console.log in my deployed app:
http://kidsvis.herokuapp.com/weather

Best wishes,
Karolin

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148188/d3-js-yaxis-not-drawing-all-the-ticks-properly). arraytime also has duplicated value and it is the one which is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the last element of your array is *exactly* the same as the first element:

```
Array[9]
  0: "2:00:00" // <-- 
  1: "5:00:00"
  2: "8:00:00"
  3: "1:00:00"
  4: "0:00:00"
  5: "3:00:00"
  6: "6:00:00"
  7: "9:00:00"
  8: "2:00:00" // <--
```

The ordinal scale is unable to differentiate between the first and the last `"2:00:00"` and returns you the value corresponding to the first `"2:00:00"`.

Consider adding the day/date to the domain to ensure that they are unique. If you do not want them in the axis, then you can use the [`tickFormat` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickFormat) to strip it out.